# Listening for updates in local storage reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage, addeventlistener

I have a form in which I ask users for their input. I will then store the input in the local storage.

```
let shape = {
   shape: shape,
   color: shapeColor,
   dimension: noOfDimension,
}
arr.push(shape)
window.localStorage.setItem("arr", JSON.stringify(arr))
```

Now I have a button in which when I click on it, a modal pops up and display the shapes stored. The shape data can be retrieved by `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("arr"))`. However the problem is, when I were to add new shape data again, it will not be reflected in the modal (unless I refresh). How can I keep listening to the local storage for updates? I have tried the following code:

```
useEffect(()=>{
        function listenForStorage(){
            const item = localStorage.getItem('arr')
            if (item) {
              setShapeList(item)
            }
          }
          window.addEventListener('storage', listenForStorage)
          return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('storage', listenForStorage)
          }
    },[])
```

The useEffect is running, but somehow, the `window.addEventListener` is not being accessed .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to listen to localstorage in react.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43313372/how-to-listen-to-localstorage-in-react-js)

Comment: @bravemaster can you please elaborate further? I don't really have any knowledge on the "old" react. I picked up on react hooks when I first started

Comment: not an answer but this library might help you: https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/docs/useLocalStorage.md

Comment: This implementation of `useLocalStorage` may help you [https://usehooks.com/useLocalStorage/](https://usehooks.com/useLocalStorage/).

Answer (score 1):

the listener you set for localStorage does not work for the active tab. You must update the state while saving the data you need to do to localStorage.

> Example

https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-nobel-ezp8f?file=/src/App.js

> Test using two tabs (console)

https://ezp8f.csb.app/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
useEffect(()=>{
        function listenForStorage(){
            const item = localStorage.getItem('arr')
            if (item) {
              setShapeList(item)
            }
          }
          window.addEventListener('storage', listenForStorage)
          return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('storage', listenForStorage)
          }
    })
```