# How to re-render a react component depending on localstorage?

Tags: reactjs

**How can i make `<FormList/>` element re-render everytime i set a new localstorage item?**

I have 2 sibling components like

```
class App extends React.Component{
  render(){
    <div>
      <MakeForm/>
      <FormList/>
    </div>
  }
}
```

What i am trying to do is simply

1. **Create new form element with multiple inputs in it from `<MakeForm/>` component and set it to the localstorage (JSON format)**
2. **Get new localstorage ıtem**
3. **Display form name and a button in `<FormList/>` for each item in localstorage**

I dont know if this helps or not but i am using **react-router-dom** module. My `<MakeForm/>` component and `<FormList/>` component has different URL's.

```
class MakeForm extends React.component{
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
    //Some properties 
  }
  }
  handleClick= () => {
    //Stringfy state's value and set localstorage item with it
  }
  render(){
    <input type="submit" onClick={this.handleClick} />

  }
}
```

```
class FormList extends React.Component{
  //Get the data from localstorage 
  render(){
    <div>
      <p>{/* Form name */}</p>
      <button>{/* Show the form */}</button>
    </div>
  } 
}
```

Every thing works just fine. But `<FormList/>` doesnt re-render. I need to refresh the page every time i make a new form in order to see new form element at home page.

**How can i make `<FormList/>` element re-render everytime i set a new localstorage item?**

Comment: you could check out `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle for class component

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to listen to localstorage in react.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43313372/how-to-listen-to-localstorage-in-react-js)

Comment: @Rashomon I dont want to listen localstorage and use forceUpdate method because it is not recommended on react docs

Comment: @wyfy Component does not update. That is the problem. How can i use `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method when the component does not update.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an open-source hook that replaces `useState` with a localStorage backed version ([available here](https://gist.github.com/coreyward/668ab5d84758001ed55da8511da08505)) that does what you're looking for. The principle is the same for a class-based function, it's just not as clean an abstraction:

```
const LocalStorage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { value: window.localStorage.getItem(props.key) }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("storage", this.handleChanges)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("storage", this.handleChanges)
  }

  handleChanges = e => {
    // only subscribe to changes to the key specified
    if (e.key === this.props.key) {
      this.setState({ value: e.newValue })
    }
  }

  // Use this instead of `setState` when setting a new value
  updateValue = newValue => {
    this.setState({ value: newValue })
    window.localStorage.setItem(this.props.key, newValue)
  }

  render() {
    return this.props.children(this.state.value, this.updateValue)
  }
}

<LocalStorage key="someProperty">
  {(value, setValue) => (
    <YourComponent someProperty={value} updateProperty={setValue} />
  )}
</LocalStorage>
```

In your case you would probably want to accept the value from localStorage as a prop to `FormList`, and then use the setter (`setValue`) to update the data in your `handleClick` method.